# GPUImage blend with self in filter chain

Tags: iphone, gpuimage

I am trying to create a filter chain where one step takes the output and blends it with itself. When I try to do this I get the error "Incomplete filter FBO: 36054". What do I need to do to make this blend use the output of a previous filter for both inputs?

```
+ (UIImage *)filter:(UIImage*)image {

    GPUImagePicture *picture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];

    // SETUP FILTERS
    GPUImageBilateralFilter *bilateralFilter = [[GPUImageBilateralFilter alloc] init];
    bilateralFilter.texelSpacingMultiplier = 2;
    bilateralFilter.distanceNormalizationFactor = 10;

    GPUImageSoftLightBlendFilter *softLightBlend = [[GPUImageSoftLightBlendFilter alloc] init];

    GPUImageNormalBlendWithAlphaFilter *masterBlend = [[GPUImageNormalBlendWithAlphaFilter alloc] init];
    masterBlend.alpha = 0;

    // SETUP PIPELINE
    [picture addTarget:bilateralFilter];
    [bilateralFilter addTarget:softLightBlend];
#if true
    [bilateralFilter addTarget:softLightBlend]; // doesn't work
#else
    [picture addTarget:softLightBlend]; // works
#endif

    [softLightBlend addTarget:masterBlend];
    [picture addTarget:masterBlend];

    // PROCESS PIPELINE
    [picture processImage];

    UIImage *result = [masterBlend imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutputWithOrientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    return result;
}
```

This simpler version also results in the same error:

```
+ (UIImage *)test:(UIImage*)image {

    GPUImagePicture *picture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];

    // SETUP FILTERS
    GPUImageSoftLightBlendFilter *softlightBlend = [[GPUImageSoftLightBlendFilter alloc] init];

    GPUImageNormalBlendWithAlphaFilter *masterBlend = [[GPUImageNormalBlendWithAlphaFilter alloc] init];
    masterBlend.alpha = .5;

    // SETUP PIPELINE
    [picture addTarget:softlightBlend];
    [picture addTarget:softlightBlend];

    [softlightBlend addTarget:masterBlend];
    [picture addTarget:masterBlend];

    // PROCESS PIPELINE
    [picture processImage];

    UIImage *result = [masterBlend imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutputWithOrientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a better way... but what I had to do was create two different GPUImagePicture objects from the *same* UIImage... and then blend these together.

What this also means if you need to blend the output of a filter with itself... you actually have to run the process up to that point and get a UIImage with imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutputWithOrientation... and then continue on... for example, something like this:

```
[picture addTarget:surfaceBlur];
[picture processImage];

UIImage *surfaceBlurResult = [surfaceBlur imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutputWithOrientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

GPUImagePicture *picture3 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:surfaceBlurResult];
GPUImagePicture *picture4 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:surfaceBlurResult];

// picture3 & picture4 are the same image (the result of surfaceBlur)
[picture3 addTarget:softlightBlendWithSelf];
[picture4 addTarget:softlightBlendWithSelf];

[picture3 processImage];
[picture4 processImage];
```